# Make Bootstrap work on Webpart resize?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, web-parts

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 site. One page can contain more than one Web Part and User can resize a Web Part as per their requirement.

Bootstrap works on a page upon window resize. Is their anyway that can make Bootstrap to work on Web Part resize?

I want make each Web Part responsive individually irrespective of screen resolution.

For example,
*I have 2 web parts in a SharePoint page with different width & height.*
*Say,
Webpart1: 800x480, Webpart2: 400x600, Window Resolution: 1920x1080*

*Now if I change the width of Webpart1 to 1200, I want Bootstrap to make only Webpart1 responsive to the new width. Webpart2 & Window resolution remains as it was.*

Any lead/help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same as https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15010